# Notepad++ add information with a link in the middle

Tags: notepad++, regex

Using Notepad++ I have the following text:

```
Testing Here One
https://test.com/random

https://test.net/random
https://test.org/random
```

I want it to become:

```
Testing Here One
https://test.com/random
Testing Here Two 
https://test.net/random
Testing Here Three
https://test.org/random
```

Link are always changing.

Answer (score 1):

Possible/partial solution:

- Find what: `(https.+$\R)(?=https|^$)`
- Replace with: `$1Testing Here\r\n`
- Search mode: Regular expression

Caveat: You need to enter one, two, three, etc by yourself.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dcduVzp.png
Here is what I received. Looks like it's not working properly.

Comment: @TrungKiên See edit.